# Change Image from Facebook send dialog.

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I Have  Used facebook send dialog in my application. every time redirect on send dialog, it shows different thumbnail. not getting how this thumbnail appears. Can we change thumbnail to custom image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The send dialog takes images from the link you want to send, you need to include an `og:image` tag if you want to show a specific picture: http://ogp.me/

Comment: added tag <meta property="og:image" content="[image url]" /> . but still image not changing from send dialog.

Comment: you have to refresh the URL in the debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: Thanks for your help. In  debugging I was getting errors related to file size. changed image and working fine.thanks.